# Is there a NON-CODING way to trigger / start a workflow on an Infopath form that will allow for secondary actions without submitting the inital form?

Tags: 2013, workflow, infopath

I think what many others are asking for has not been answered yet in any variations of the questions posed.

As a designer of a workflow, I'm using InfoPath to capture data from an end-user and I'm displaying previously captured data from previous steps.  On each and every action I have, I have a separate InfoPath form, I'm looking to be able to add one simple button (with a standard rule or set of actions) that will trigger a workflow to capture interim information, which may or may not be able to be displayed back to my end-user form prior to submitting the task as completed.  IE. Capturing important comments that need to be documented while that workflow task is active, which is only true when the form hasn't been submitted.

I also want this trigger to be re-usable on this specific SharePoint site, not just the current SharePoint list.

I am not a developer so writing code is not going to happen and I don't have developers around me to help in this aspect.

If it's just a matter of sending a YES/NO value back to the SharePoint List to trigger a separate workflow, I could live with this, but I cannot seem to get the InfoPath form to allow anything more than a Retrieve Data action to happen on a form load.  And as I stated above, I don't want to submit or complete the form yet to trigger this sub-workflow.

Can you please elaborate on this type of functionality, and possible solutions and not deem this as a DUPLICATE question as others?

Answer (score 0):

Workflows run on items in SharePoint lists and libraries, so there is no way to run a workflow without a library entry to run it on. So no, you can't do it exactly like you are thinking about doing it. The good news is that there's a way you can get (almost) the same functionality you're looking for by doing a little finagling. You need the users to submit their forms to the library at each step of the way, then run the workflow whenever an item is added to or modified in the library. I'm under the impression that you want your library to only have completed tasks in it. Instead, why not add a "status" column that differentiates between in-progress and completed tasks, then use view filters to only show completed tasks on your site? The default value of this column can be "in-progress", and the submit button on the final form can change that value to "completed" prior to submitting. If you have any existing workflows that run when a completed item is submitted to your library as it exists now, you'll have to add a check to only run when the status is equal to "completed".

Are there any other requirements driving your desire to not submit in-progress forms? I'm pretty sure they can all be worked around.

The only alternative that would allow you to "run a workflow" without submitting the form would be to convert all the workflow logic into rules, actions, and code on the InfoPath form itself; that might be possible to do without "writing code" in the VBA/C# sense of the phrase, but it depends on what exactly you wanted the workflow to do.

Edit: I forgot about site workflows that don't run on specific items, but they still won't be able to get any data from your in-progress forms until they're submitted, and you won't be able to call those without writing code. Perhaps some more information about what your workflow is intended to do would help me be clearer in my answer.